# How can I prevent the screen from going black in vnc when inactive?

Tags: vnc

When I'm using VNC, the screen goes black after an inactivity for around 2 seconds. If I move the mouse or press a key the screen goes back however this is very annoying.
I have KDE 4.10 on both systems, I'm tunneling the VNC through the SSH connection (`ssh -R5900:localhost:5900 myhost`) from the server to my local computer.

I'm using `x11vnc` as a server and Tight VNC as a client.

I've tried different vnc clients (vinagre, real vnc, xvnc4viewer) but the issue remains. 
Also, I've tried different settings to `x11vnc server (-sb 0 -nonap -noxdamage etc)` but nothing works for me.

There is a [thread on kubuntuforums](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?50181-krfb-_-vnc-client-screen-goes-black-after-a-few-seconds) with the same issue, but doesn't seem to be resolved.

Do any of you have some idea what can be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

on the server issue the following command:

```
xset dpms force on
```